# How do I implement Rate Limiting for app with webforms in .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, global-asax, .net-4.8

I am working on a legacy app with webforms in .net framework. and I need to implement Rate Limiting functionality for the login page, here the Login action is event based written in code behind file (login.aspx.cs)
`void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}`

my login action triggers on submit click which is attach as event to handler.
`cmdSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(cmdSubmit_Click);`

whatever I have looked so far is all pointing towards the .net core solution with webapithrottle and actionfilter methods.
or deals with startup.cs or program.cs but nothing related to the Global.ascx which we are using.

I am not sure If I can implement the action filter method here or not.
If yes can you please help me out how.

Is there any other way I can implement the rate limiting on my login action.

Comment: I know this wont be a super helpful comment, but perhaps you can try creating an asp.net core project and looking into the rate limiting middleware which comes with it. You will have to refactor a lot of things, but it shouldn't be too difficult to make it work (hopefully)

Comment: with that being said, are you sure rate limiting is the way to go? why not implement a lockout mechanism within your authentication middleware? if you are using ASP.NET Identity, it has this feature already, and it should be easy to configure the service.

Comment: I just have a system.Threading.Thread.sleep(1000) seconds, and show a spinner. So, if you looking to limit the number of logons, and the speed at which they can be done? Just toss in a 1 second delay if their logon is incorrect. You could I suppose then increase it to 2 seconds, and then say 4. And after 5 or so, then you could lock out that acount or force user to re-set their password

Comment: Nope, i am using net.framework as I am working on a legacy app build with webforms. as for current .net core projects they have various inbuild ways to rate limit on api calls. but I want to specifically apply it only on Login page/api call as a cover to brut force attack.